# Rootless custom scheduling of Time Machine backups

Tags: macos, time-machine, customization, sip

It has been asked [how to customize the backup schedule of Time Machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81789/custom-scheduling-of-time-machine-backups), but the solutions in the answers only seem to work in releases of OS X that weren’t “rootless”, i.e. before 10.11 *El Capitan* (or was it 10.10 already?). The recommended tool [Time Machine Scheduler](http://klieme.com/TimeMachineScheduler.html) also doesn’t seem to have been updated since 2013.

Is there a solution to adjust the backup intervals for current (2015+) versions of OS X?

Comment: Disable SIP, make changes, enable SIP.

Comment: [tag:sip] is the tag for System Integrity Protection questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the existing solutions from the existing question [Custom Scheduling of Time Machine backups](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81789/custom-scheduling-of-time-machine-backups) by [disabling System Integrity Protection first](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/) using `csrutil disable` in Terminal from the Recovery HD. Once the changes have been made, you can re-enable SIP by running the same command but using ‘enable’ in the place of ‘disable’, also from Terminal in the Recovery HD.

Comment: Indeed, there’s a quite [popular question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) for that. I’ll keep this one open, though, in case there is (or will be) a solution without disabling SIP.

Comment: @Crissov, At the present time there is no other solution but to disable SIP and I do not see Apple changing that any time soon.